# htaccess question - example123.ca/a/ < takes me to a 404 page, why doesn't it take me to the index.html thats inside the "a" folder?

Tags: .htaccess

this URL `example123.ca` takes me to the `index.html`, and adds in the HTTPS...

but `example123.ca/a/` takes me to a 404 page, why doesn't it take me to the `index.html` that's inside the `a` folder?

I added this to the root `.htaccess` to remove the `WWW.` and forces HTTPS.

```
#forces HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#removes WWW
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

and in the `a` folder `.htaccess` has this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "a"
AuthUserFile "/home/a4af6ec6cl5p/.htpasswds/public_html/a/passwd"
require valid-user
```

Comment: Are you getting prompted for a username/password? And are you entering these credentials correctly? _Aside:_ Your second `RewriteRule` should be redirecting to `https://`, not `http://`.

Comment: What version of Apache (or LiteSpeed?) are you using?

Comment: "I know about the username and password." - Ok, but are you getting prompted - is the HTTP basic auth "working"? If not (you've not said either way) then that would help resolve this problem. Is the 404 page you are seeing generated by Apache or something else? Please edit your question to include the exact response. And please clarify the webserver and version. Thanks.

Comment: Hi MrWhite,
----------
Thanks for your replies, I know about the username and password. I put that in place. and thanks ,  I will update the second RewriteRule.
----------
and this issue still there,
----------
this one: 
example123.ca/a
loads a 404 error
----------
and this one : 
www.example123.ca/a
loads a 404 error
----------
and this one: https://example123.ca/a
loads correctly, prompt for username and password.
----------
my question is, why doesnt the first 2 load the https, while this one: 
example123.ca
does load correctly the https
----------

Comment: yes the basic auth is working

Comment: If you (temporarily) remove the HTTP basic auth directives, does it work?

Comment: ok I will try that right now....

Comment: your awesome! yes that does work. is there a way to have the basic auth ?

its for a dev site. the live root directory has a coming soon page and the business is not ready for a couple of months.

Comment: Please clarify the web server and version. It looks like you might be on LiteSpeed, not Apache?

Comment: And what is triggering the 404 response? Please edit your question to include the exact response you are seeing. Including the HTTP response headers.

Comment: Thanks MrWhite - here is the server and version from cpanel - Apache Version2.4.51

Comment: here is the 404 error, seems like a basic 404...Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. -------------

i suppose the issue comes to .... when I remove the basic auth, the browser finds the "a' folder, when I type "example.ca/a" and with the same url with the basic auth ON it results in a 404 error.